# problem make token bsc (Low level interactions)

Tags: token, solidity, binance-smart-chain

i make token in remix.eth but get error , Low level interactions
( Both 'receive' and 'fallback' functions are not defined)

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab, there's a selectbox allowing you to chose which of the contracts you want to deploy as the main contract. It's sorted alphabetically, so the `Address` (one of the contracts listed in the linked `.sol` file) comes as the first and default option.

You most likely wanted to **deploy the `COMF` contract** instead.

---

The `Address` contract is a helper library. It doesn't have any `public` and `external` functions, so the list of available functions to call is empty.

It also doesn't have the `receive()` and `fallback()` functions, so the low-level call with empty payload fails with the "Both 'receive' and 'fallback' functions are not defined" message.

Comment: very thanks,worked.